# Does Web.config also effect .html file?

Tags: asp.net

I upload an index.html to asp.net hosting, it works well.
After I add a web.config file to the website, I get the following error when I try to visit index.html again. Why?
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

You can download the code at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/209352/Html5Demo.zip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="offline.manifest">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cats Who Code demo</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header class="ma-class-en-css">
            <h1 id="logo">
                <a href="#">Cats Who Code</a></h1>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>
                Paris, France</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
            <p>
                Integer faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- #content -->
        <footer>A demo by <a href="http://www.catswhocode.com">CatsWhoCode</a></footer>
    </div>
    <!-- #container -->
</body>
</html>



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the hosting asp .net server properly configured to support framework 4.0? Can you check the server logs? They will probably give you a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML files are still hosted in the App. If there is a problem with the web.config the app will not load properly which will prevent your html file from displaying.